# Test Python Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, тестирование

прохожу собеседование на работу, дали задание написать тест для определенного сайта.
Я написал просто в виде нескольких функций и главного метода, который применяет эти функции.

Как правильно писать тест, какая его структура? Просто до этого этим не занимался. Если будет пример от людей, которые этим занимаются, будет просто прекрасно.

На данный момент мой скрипт представлен так:

```
import time
import logging
import random
import string
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
import re
import unittest

db_bd = "test"
db_user = "root"
db_password = ""
db_host = "localhost"

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)

url_main = "http://tereshkova.test.kavichki.com/"
time_waiting_item = 5  #Время ожидание появления элемента


#Функция генерации случайной строки, только ASCII
def random_string(size, type):
    types = ("name", "count", "price")
    if type in types:
        if(type == "name"):
            chars = string.ascii_lowercase
        else:
            chars = string.digits
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
    else:
        log.info("Вы не правильно указали тип генерируемой строки для. Должно быть name, count или price. Конец программы.")
        exit(8)



#Функция отправки запроса к базе данных
def query_database(sql_query, data, type):
    types = ("insert", "select")
    if type in types:
        try:
            conn = MySQLConnection(user=db_user, password=db_password, host=db_host, database=db_bd)
            conn.autocommit = True
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            try:
                cursor.execute(sql_query, data)
                if(type == "insert"):
                    # Возврат идентификатора добавленной строки
                    return cursor.lastrowid
                elif(type == "select"):
                    # Возврат кортеж значения запроса
                    rows = cursor.fetchall()
                    return rows
            except Exception as e:
                log.info("Ошибка запроса: %s. Конец программы", e)
                exit(6)
            finally:
                cursor.close()
                conn.close()
        except Exception as e:
            log.info("Ошибка подключения к базе данных: %s. Конец программы", e)
            exit(6)

    else:
        log.info("Вы не правильно указали тип SQL - запроса. Должно быть select или insert. Конец программы.")
        exit(5)


#Инициализация driver
def init_driver():
    ff = "../install/chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # chrome_option.add_argument("headless")  #Режим headless
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}  #Настройка, которая отключает загрузку изображений
    chrome_option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    try:
        return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, options=chrome_option)
    except SessionNotCreatedException:
        print("Ошибка инициализации браузера. Скорее всего у вас не установлен браузер. Пожалуйста обратитесь к разработчику парсера")

#Парсинг товаров на сайте
def parse(driver):
    rows = []
    try:
        table = driver.find_element_by_id("tbl")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Элемент не найден. Конец программы")
        exit(3)
    #Нахождение записей в таблице на сайте
    tr_list = table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tbody > tr')
    if(len(tr_list) == 0):
        print("Элементы tr не найдены. Конец программы")
        exit(4)
    for tr in tr_list:
        td_list = tr.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')
        if(len(td_list) != 4):
            print("Количество элементов td не соответствует 4. Возможно поменялась разметка. Конец программы")
            exit(5)
        name = td_list[0].text.strip()
        count = td_list[1].text.strip()
        price = td_list[2].text.strip()
        temp = []
        temp.append(name)
        temp.append(count)
        temp.append(price)
        log.info("Товар: %s, количество: %s, цена: %s", name, count, price)

        rows.append(temp)
    print(rows)
    return rows

#Функция добавления новых товаров на сайте
def add_new_purchase_site(driver, cound_add):
    add_list = []
    for count in range(cound_add):
        try:
            #Кнопка добавление новой записи на сайте
            a_id_open = driver.find_element_by_id("open")
            a_id_open.click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("Элемент не найден. Конец программы")
            exit(7)
        try:
            div_class_new = WebDriverWait(driver, time_waiting_item).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#new")))
        except TimeoutException:
            log.info("Элемент div с id = new не найден. Увеличьте время ожидание появления элемента в переменной time_waiting_item или проверьте разметку. Конец программы")
            exit(8)
        try:
            input_id_name = div_class_new.find_element_by_id("name")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            log.info("Элемент input с id = name не найден. Конец программы")
            exit(9)

        #Вводим случайную строку в поле с длинной строки = 5
        name = random_string(5, "name")
        input_id_name.send_keys(name)

        try:
            input_id_count = div_class_new.find_element_by_id("count")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            log.info("Элемент input с id = count не найден. Конец программы")
            exit(10)
        # Вводим случайную строку в поле с длинной строки = 2
        count = random_string(2, "count")
        input_id_count.send_keys(count)

        try:
            input_id_price = div_class_new.find_element_by_id("price")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            log.info("Элемент input с id = price не найден. Конец программы")
            exit(11)
        # Вводим случайную строку в поле с длинной строки = 2
        price = random_string(2, "price")
        input_id_price.send_keys(price)
        time.sleep(5)
        try:
            input_id_add = div_class_new.find_element_by_id("add").click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            log.info("Элемент input с id = add не найден. Конец программы")
            exit(12)
        add_list.append([name, count, price])
        #Очистка Input-ов
        input_id_name.clear()
        input_id_count.clear()
        input_id_price.clear()

    return add_list

#Метод определяющий разница двух многомерных списков
def different_list(list1, list2):
    #list2 > list1
    # diff=[x for x in list1 if x not in [y for y in list2]]
    diff = [x for x in list1 if x[0] not in [y[0] for y in list2]]
    return diff

def main(url):
    # Проверка на некорретность ссылок
    text_search = re.search("^http", url)
    if (text_search == None):
        log.info("Ссылка %s некорректна. Конец программы", url)
        exit(1)

    log.info("Запуск браузера")
    driver = init_driver()

    log.info("Переход на %s", url)
    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Ошибка перехода. Конец программы", e)  # Не отслеживается
        exit(2)

    #Получаем список с сайта
    rows_table = parse(driver)

    # Добавление в базу данных
    for row in rows_table:
        sql_query = "INSERT INTO purchase(name, count, price) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
        query_database(sql_query, row, "insert")

    list_add_in_table_site = add_new_purchase_site(driver, 4)

    #Получаем записи из БД
    sql_query = "SELECT name, count, price FROM purchase"
    set_in_database = query_database(sql_query, None, "select")

    log.info("------------------------Повторный парсинг страницы-----------")
    list_purchase_in_table_site = parse(driver)
    print(list_add_in_table_site)
    print(list_purchase_in_table_site)
    print(set_in_database)
    print("Отсутствуют в базе данных:", different_list(list_purchase_in_table_site, list_add_in_table_site))
    print("Имеются и в базе данных и на сайте", different_list(list_add_in_table_site, list(set_in_database)))
    time.sleep(1000)
    driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    unittest.main()
    main(url_main)
    log.info("Время работы: %s", time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Мне кажется тут не правильная конечная цель тестов, каждый тест должен проверять один случай (обычно через assert). Например тест добавления записи в таблицу должен проходить так: Заходим на страницу с таблицей, вводим нужные данные, нажимаем добавить, через assert, проверяем, что добавилось. На вход подаем различные данные, пишем еще пару тестов на проверку ввода валидных  и не валидных данных. Тесты на добавление записи готовы, далее пишем тесты на редактирование записи. И в таком духе.

Comment: @user2455111 ну вот у вас есть любой пример теста, чтобы  по нему отредактировал свой скрипт

Comment: тут есть https://habr.com/post/250921/

Comment: Я сходу ничего не понял что Вы хотите сделать...

По-хорошему каждый тест должен проверять только одну вещь и должен быть независим от других тестов. Кроме того тест может содежрать setup и teardown, которые всё готовят для теста и всё чистят после теста.

Comment: @nick_gabpe вот описание задания: При помощи браузера Google Chrome под управлением Selenium, собрать данные из таблицы, находящейся тут http://tereshkova.test.kavichki.com в вашу таблицу на сервере, распарсив данные. Далее заполнить некоторыми данными таблицу на сайте «Терешкова», сравнить ее результаты с вашей БД и с теми данными, которые вы на самом деле вводили и вывести результат об изменениях

Comment: @nick_gabpe по сути это один тест так ведь?

Comment: Я бы, наверное, сделал одним тестом.